# How to read the statement "If for every subset B' of B, it holds that α ∈ Cn(B') iff β ∈ Cn(B'), then B - α = B - β"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

I'm confused specifically about the second part of the "iff".

For the first part "if for every subset B' of B, it holds that α ∈ Cn(B')" I understand that it is saying that α ∈ Cn(B') must hold for any subset B' of B.

But in the second part, specifically "if β ∈ Cn(B')", what B' is it refering to? Is it every subset B' as well or is it an arbitrary B'?

Comment: There is a condition with iff; if that condition holds, then...

Comment: The way I understand this statement is this, when translated with quantifiers:
$$\bigg(\forall B' \subset B, \Big(\alpha \in \operatorname{Cn}(B') \Leftrightarrow \beta \in \operatorname{Cn}(B')\Big)\bigg) \Longrightarrow B - \alpha = B - \beta$$
Note that I do not know what $\operatorname{Cn}$ stands for or if it's supposed to be written $C_n$ or some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **If** for every subset B' of B, it holds that α ∈ C(B') iff β ∈ C(B'), **then** B - α = B - β

( for every subset B' of B, it holds that α ∈ C(B') iff β ∈ C(B') ) $\;\implies\;$ B - α = B - β

$\bigg(\forall B'{\subseteq}B\; \Big(α ∈ C(B') \iff β ∈ C(B')\Big) \bigg) \implies B - α = B - β$